# Why does NgFor render "template_bindings = {}" in the DOM instead of the data-bound elements in my Component?

Tags: angular, typescript

When I inspect the data (cities and counties) in DevTools, it's being loaded properly. Everything on the template is loading properly too (no errors being thrown), except that the values of the `option` elements aren't rendering. Unfortunately, because Angular 2 just went beta, the syntax is different depending on when X blog post was written, or when Y SO question was asked, or even which page on angular.io you're looking at. No idea what I'm missing here.

I realize assigning the `value` attr and adding text is probably overkill, but neither makes a difference.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgFor} from 'angular2/common';
import {City, County, RegionalData} from './interfaces';
import {api} from './api.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'geo-selector',
    template: `
        <div>
            <select name="region-selector">
                <optgroup label="Cities">
                    <option *ngFor="#city of cities" selected="selected" [value]="city.name">{{city.name}}</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Counties">
                    <option *ngFor="#county of counties" [value]="county.name">{{county.name}}</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
            <label for="">Zip Search</label>
            <input type="text" name="zip-search"/>
        </div>
                        `,
    providers: [api],
    directives: [NgFor]
})

export class GeoSelector {
        public cities: City[];
        public counties: County[];

        constructor(private _api:api) {
            this.getRegions();
        }

        getRegions(): void {
            this._api.getRegions().then(function(data: RegionalData) {
                this.cities = data.cities;
                this.counties = data.counties;
            });
        }

        onSelect() {

        }

}
```

When I inspect the elements in DevTools, in the space where the `option` elements should be, I see this:

```
<!--template bindings={}-->
```

A clue: I see that the comment is being rendered by `setBindingDebugInfo` in `angular2/ts/src/platform/dom/dom_renderer.ts`, which is "used only in debug mode to serialize property changes to comment nodes, such as <template> placeholders."

Comment: You are also not binding promise success callback to proper context. Should be `this._api.getRegions().then((data: RegionalData) => { this.cities = data.cities; this.counties = data.counties; });`

Comment: Yes in fact, when using callback function, the `this` keyword corresponds to the object your callback is executed on. With ES6 arrow functions (=>), the `this` keyword is now the context around...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getRegions` promise callback is not properly written

```
getRegions(): void {
   this._api.getRegions().then((data: RegionalData) => { 
          this.cities = data.cities;
          this.counties = data.counties;
    });
}
```

use this notation, otherwise `this` refers to the callback function, instead of the GeoSelector class

Comment: Ah! That's it. Thanks -- not too familiar with that notation yet.